# Deploying a sample Spring Web MVC project

Tags: spring, tomcat, spring-mvc

I'm new to Tomcat, Maven and Spring Web MVC (framework v3 to be precise). I was trying to build the [example](https://anonsvn.springframework.org/svn/spring-samples/) project `mvc-basic` so that I could deploy the generated WAR file on a test server (not locally) and analyse the effects.

When I run Maven in the directory containing `pom.xml`, I see these vague error messages.

```
pdedecker@linux-qhij:~/Dropbox/Unief/GWT/mvc/mvc-basic/trunk> ~/Apps/apache-maven-3.0.3/bin/mvn pom.xml
[INFO] Scanning for projects...                                                                                                                                                                      
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for org.springframework.samples:mvc-basic:war:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
[WARNING] 'build.plugins.plugin.version' for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin is missing. @ line 124, column 12
[WARNING] 'build.plugins.plugin.version' for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin is missing. @ line 133, column 12
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] It is highly recommended to fix these problems because they threaten the stability of your build.
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] For this reason, future Maven versions might no longer support building such malformed projects.
[WARNING] 
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building mvc-basic 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.132s
[INFO] Finished at: Thu Apr 28 13:26:39 CEST 2011
[INFO] Final Memory: 2M/57M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Unknown lifecycle phase "pom.xml". You must specify a valid lifecycle phase or a goal in the format <plugin-prefix>:<goal> or <plugin-group-id>:<plugin-artifact-id>[:<plugin-version>]:<goal>. Available lifecycle phases are: validate, initialize, generate-sources, process-sources, generate-resources, process-resources, compile, process-classes, generate-test-sources, process-test-sources, generate-test-resources, process-test-resources, test-compile, process-test-classes, test, prepare-package, package, pre-integration-test, integration-test, post-integration-test, verify, install, deploy, pre-clean, clean, post-clean, pre-site, site, post-site, site-deploy. -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/LifecyclePhaseNotFoundException
```

I have little to no knowledge about the things mentioned by the compiler. How can I generate the WAR file? Which tools am I missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to run `mvn package`.

WAR file will appear in `target` subfolder after running it.

**See also:**

- [Maven in 5 Minutes](http://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/maven-in-five-minutes.html)

Answer (score 2):

Open Terminal, cd to the directory containing your project and type the following

```
$ mvn tomcat:deploy
```

That will put the WAR file into your tomcat installation webapps folder.

But first you might want to make sure everything is set up properly. For more info, here is  [how to deploy a Maven webapp to Tomcat](http://bitbybitblog.com/deploy-to-tomcat/) and there you will also find how to add Spring MVC 3, Hibernate, etc