# Fail of org.apache.maven.plugins goal execution

Tags: maven, maven-plugin

I'm trying to generate a war file using maven but i'm getting this error (most of downloading log output is omitted to make log more clear):

```
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-war-plugin/2.1.1/maven-war-plugin-2.1.1.pom
Downloaded: 
...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building tn.talan.selenium Maven Webapp 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.4.1:clean (default-clean) @ tn.talan.selenium ---
...
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.5:resources (default-resources) @ tn.talan.selenium ---
...
[INFO] --- maven-war-plugin:2.1.1:war (default-cli) @ tn.talan.selenium ---
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/maven-archiver/2.4.1/maven-archiver-2.4.1.pom
Downloaded: 
...
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
...
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:2.1.1:war (default-cli) on project tn.talan.selenium: Execution default-cli of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:2.1.1:war failed: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:2.1.1 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Could not transfer artifact org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-io:jar:1.0.1 from/to central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): GET request of: org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-io/1.0.1/plexus-io-1.0.1.jar from central failed: Read timed out -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
...
```

Here's my pom.xml file code:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-
 v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>selenium</groupId>
  <artifactId>tn.talan.selenium</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>tn.talan.selenium Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <finalName>tn.talan.selenium</finalName>

    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
      </plugin>

      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-beta-1</version>
      </plugin>

    </plugins>

  </build>

</project>
```

What's wrong with my pom? Any idea please?

Comment: Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5817980/102937

Comment: and here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10680467

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Specify version for `maven-war-plugin`, e.g.

```xml
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.2</version>
</plugin>
```

Comment: it really helped me

Comment: thanks, to see other versions of maven plugin: https://maven.apache.org/plugins/index.html

Answer (score 2):

For solving this error, you don't need to do anything, just change your jdk version. You can prefer any jdk version but don't prefer latest one.Try to use older version. Recommended : JDK 11.0.11